# how to identify the object touched the Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch

The question is simple, how can I identify which object has been touched by the user in OpenGL.
I've tried the utilizat envento onTouchEvent but this only returns the possição X, Y screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android OpenGL 3D picking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699387/android-opengl-3d-picking)

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked (& answered) in this thread: 
[Detect user's touches over an OpenGL square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154272/detect-users-touches-over-an-opengl-square)

Basically there are 2 methods: 1 rendering all objects to a buffer in all different colours and then looking at the colour information at the specified 'pick coordinate' to identify your object.
The other (and I think less resource intensive) is retrieving the 'ray' and then doing a hit test with bounding boxes you provide for all your objects currently rendered on the screen.

edit: 
If you're doing your rendering orthographically/2d then this somewhat simplifies things.
You can do a simple hit Test with the point you touched and a rectangle (or circle or polygon perhaps) you provide for the image that you've drawn.

Hope this helps.