# How to detect 3d model touch in opengl es?

Tags: opengl-es, touch, symbian

How to detect weather the user is touching the 3d model/object in opengl es on a symbian devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine what is touched in 3D space from the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487710/how-do-i-determine-what-is-touched-in-3d-space-from-the-screen)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone OpenGL ES - How to Pick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540447/iphone-opengl-es-how-to-pick)